# Python script take long time to backup folder

Tags: backup, bash, python, tar

I copied this script from some book to make tar.bz2 of some folders for backup.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import tarfile, os

def make_tar(folder_to_backup, dest_folder, compression='bz2'):
        if compression:
                dest_ext ='.' + compression
        else:
                dest_ext = ''
        arcname = os.path.basename(folder_to_backup)
        dest_name = '%s.tar%s' % (arcname, dest_ext)
        dest_path = os.path.join(dest_folder, dest_name)
        if compression:
                dest_cmp = ':' + compression
        else:
                dest_cmp = ''

        out = tarfile.TarFile.open(dest_path, 'w' +dest_cmp)
        out.add(folder_to_backup, arcname)
        out.close()
        return dest_path

print "Doing Python"
make_tar('/home/bob/public_html','/home/bob/testbck', compression='bz2')
```

Now bash take 40 second to make backup of that folder and python takes around 8 minutes.

Am i wrong somewhere or python is always slower for these tasks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied/pasted your code and tried with both `bz2` and `gz` against `tar cjpf` and `tar czpf` respectively and found them to perform the same. Which version of Python are you using? How many files are there on `/home/bob/public_html`? Did you try the tar command first and then your script or the other way around? (I'm guessing file caches may skew the results a bit, but not so much though).

I just took a look to TarFile's implementation. It's easy with `ipython`, by the way:

```
import tarfile
%edit tarfile.TarFile.add
```

And this is the case for directories:

```
    elif tarinfo.isdir():
        self.addfile(tarinfo)
        if recursive:
            for f in os.listdir(name):
                self.add(os.path.join(name, f), os.path.join(arcname, f), recursive, exclude)
```

Which I can see getting slower as the number of total files increases. I'm guessing `tar` may be more optimized when handling this case. It's just a guess, though.

Comment: its working now , actually i was compairing linux tar.gz with pyhton tar.bz2 which had different times , now i have chnaged to gz and its almost same. that was my first python script . very happy now

Comment: Ah, that explains it of course! I should have thought of that possibility. Have fun with Python and take a look at `ipython`, it lets you try your code on the go much more easily than the standard interpreter. You can also call it from your scripts to "debug" interactively.

Comment: i am using linux termnal by writing .py files and then executing. how can ipython help me . does it has more commands and also how will my .py script chnage if i want to use ipython

Comment: No new commands or anything - it's just a way to execute python interactively, allowing greater flexibility when developing. No need to use it for your script at all, it was more of a general recommendation.